# Read csv and print column names and values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv I would like to read csv and printout the column name and it related value
e.g.:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | def | fgh |

Sample output

```
Col : 'abc'
Col2: 'def'
col3: 'fgh'
```

Code:

```
import csv

with open('employee.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
      print row[0]
```

Please advise how we can display the column name and value.

Comment: Does your CSV file start with a header row containing (literally) the names `col1,col2,col3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('employee.csv')

for col in df.columns:
    print(col+':', df[col][0])
```

for your example above

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col' : 'abc', 'Col2': 'def', 'col3': 'fgh'}, index=[0])
for col in df.columns:
        print(col+':', df[col][0])
```

prints

```
Col: abc
Col2: def
col3: fgh
```

Comment: Thanks alot appreciate!,

Comment: also @keith what if i need to pick only specific columns...how do i filter?

Comment: if you just want one column: df['column_name'] or df.colum_name will give you that column. For multiple, you can pass a list of column names: df[['Col', 'Col2']] for example